# Javascript opened ports scanner

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip, port, child-process

I'm doing an ip port scanner in js using node.js.
I launch a function using a command looking like this : *>getports 127.0.0.0*
And i want to see all port that could be use to do a deny of service.

Here is my code :

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec(`netstat -an ${args[0]} | findstr "ESTABLISHED"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if(error){
    console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }else if(stdout){
    console.log(`Found :\n${stdout.slice(0, 1980)}`); // I just want the 1980 first chars
    return;
  }else if(stderr){
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
});
```

The command executed : netstat -an 127.0.0.0 | findstr "ESTABLISHED"

I'm blocked cause the process never end. So i never get the response...

Comment: Just a suggestion: "ETABLISHED" seems to be a misspelling.

Comment: Yes mb, i changed it, but doesn't fix my problem :/

Comment: What do you expect to be in args[0]? And can you console.log the exec string?

Comment: The args[0] is the ip adress i provided in command*

Comment: The javascript works on my machine. Please run the command `netstat -an 127.0.0.1 | findstr "ESTABLISHED"` in a console to make sure the command works on your machine.

Comment: it is working on my machine

Answer (score 0):

3. **exec**

***This method will spawn a subshell and execute the command in that shell and buffer generated data. When the child process completes, callback function will be called with:
buffered data when the command executes successfully***

When you run ***netstat -an 127.0.0.1*** from your cmd, you can see that the command still continues to run until you send a stop signal...

So, if you want to get the output to the buffer I suggest you to spawn a cmd.exe and execute netstat.exe from that

```
function run_cmd(cmd, args, cb, end) {
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn(cmd, args),
    me = this;
child.stdout.on('data', function (buffer) { cb(me, buffer) });
child.stdout.on('end', end);
}

// Run C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe -an
var foo = new run_cmd(
    'netstat.exe', ['-an'],
    function (me, buffer) { me.stdout += buffer.toString() },
    function () { console.log(foo.stdout) }
);
```

something like this